# ROS Cmake Error in lsb.cmake:8 (string): string no output variable specified

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying to compile a workspace using catkin_make I get a CMake error. I think that this has to do with the python installation. The catkin_make has compiled in the the past and I have not changed /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/platform/lsb.cmake. I am using ubuntu 14.04 and a ROS version of indigo. Does anyone else know where this problem is coming from?

The error occurs when I run:

```
~$ cd catkin_ws_working_copy
~/catkin_ws_working_copy$ catkin_make
```

I get this error:

```
 ####
    #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "catkin_ws_working_copy/build"
    ####
    -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /catkin_ws_working_copy/devel
    -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /catkin_ws_working_copy/devel;/catkin_ws/devel;/sawyer_ros/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
    -- This workspace overlays: /catkin_ws_working_copy/devel;/catkin_ws/devel;/sawyer_ros/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
    -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
    -- Using Debian Python package layout
    -- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy 

CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/platform/lsb.cmake:8 (string):   string no output variable specified Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)   /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)   CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)
    
    
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/platform/lsb.cmake:21 (string):   string no output variable specified Call Stack (most recent call first):   /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)   /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)   CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)
```

I have not changed the lsb.cmake file and it is below:

```
find_program(LSB_RELEASE_EXECUTABLE lsb_release)

if(LSB_RELEASE_EXECUTABLE)
  set(LSB_FOUND TRUE CACHE BOOL "lsb_release executable was found")
  execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE_EXECUTABLE} -si
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_DISTRIB_ID
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  string(TOUPPER ${LSB_DISTRIB_ID} v)
  set(${v} TRUE CACHE BOOL "LSB Distrib tag")

  execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE_EXECUTABLE} -sd
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_DESCRIPTION
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE_EXECUTABLE} -sr
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_RELEASE
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  execute_process(COMMAND ${LSB_RELEASE_EXECUTABLE} -sc
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE LSB_CODENAME
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)

  string(TOUPPER ${LSB_DISTRIB_ID} v)
  set(${v} TRUE CACHE BOOL "LSB Distribution")
  #message(STATUS "${v} is on")

  string(TOUPPER ${LSB_DISTRIB_ID}_${LSB_CODENAME} v)
  set(${v} TRUE CACHE BOOL "LSB Distrib - codename tag")
  #message(STATUS "${v} is on")
endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328274/ros-cmake-error-in-lsb.cmake:8-(string):-string-no-output-variable-specified/) by [jonbbbb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44033/jonbbbb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-11**:
This appears to be a cross-post of [ROS Cmake Error in lsb.cmake:8 (string): string no output variable specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56991924/).

Could you please not do that? It leads to split discussions at best and duplicated (ie: wasted) effort in any case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-11**:
What is the output of `lsb_release -si`?

**Comment by [AyaO](https://answers.ros.org/users/38650/ayao/) on 2019-07-23**:
I have the same problem as jonbbbb ? Did you find any solution ?
The post mentionned by gvdhoorn was removed.

**Comment by [jonbbbb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44033/jonbbbb/) on 2019-07-24**:
I never found a solution. I moved my work space to a different computer, and my programs worked fine. So I have just been working on a different linux machine.

**Comment by [Anubhav Singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/44804/anubhav-singh/) on 2021-03-15**:
super @jeremy.roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've run into this issue a few times as well.  It generally occurs after I install a new version of python on my machine.  I don't fully understand the source of the problem, but re-installing `lsb-release` generally works:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall lsb-release
```

---

Originally posted by [jeremy.roy](https://answers.ros.org/users/32339/jeremy.roy/) with karma: 16 on 2020-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2